# How would I go about adding a value to all numbers in a linked list?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

So, I'm having trouble understanding the process for a function that would take the value passed into a method called in the main and add that value to all the numbers in a linked list already stored in a node variable. A function prototype for this could look like:

```
void IntegerListClass::AdjustNumbers(int changeValue);
```

where change value is the number passed into the call and added to all the numbers in the linked list.

I'm thinking something like this, but I get an error on the left side of the equation in the while loop saying that the value needs to be a modifiable l-value:

```
void IntegerListClass::AdjustNumbers(int changeValue)
{
    nodePtr current;

    current = start;

    while (current != NULL)
    {

        current = current->link;

        current->data.number + changeValue = current->data.number //error here

    }
}
```

Comment: As you can imagine, how to do this is rooted entirely in how you implemented your `IntegerListClass` class, which we know nothing about.

Comment: Step 1: do you know how to iterate over your list?

Comment: Whatever logic allowed you to correctly determine it should be `current = current->link` should be applied to the statement above it.

Comment: Ummm what is the meaning of this `current->data.number + changeValue = current->data.number`? Is it `current->data.number += changeValue`?

Comment: @luk32 Oh no no no. Say for example that current->data.number is the first number in my linked list is 32. This statement would add that value to the changeValue, which is 100, and then go through the rest of the linked list performing that operation.

Comment: @Smiter your existing line with `+` is nonsense. You cannot have `+` on the left side of `=`. luk32 was speculating that, for each number in the list, you want to add `changeValue` to that number (and save the result in the same place).  If that is not actually what you want then you need to be more clear in your question.

Comment: @M.M Yep, you are correct. I do apologize. It's just that being I'm so new to this, it's difficult to come up with an understandable vocabulary to articulate my problems.

Comment: The code with "current = current->link;" before the addition is buggy.  As it will miss the first node and then run off the end.  You have to have that as the last statement in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because for some reason you wrote:

`current->data.number + changeValue = current->data.number;`

The technical reason for the error is that the addition produces a prvalue (the result of `current->data.number + changeValue`), to which you want to assign the old value. That's why compiler complains that you need an `l-value` at the left side. `prvalues` cannot be assigned to.

Relevant sections of [`value_category`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category):

> A prvalue ("pure rvalue") expression is an expression that does not have identity and can be moved from.
>   The following expressions are prvalue expressions:
>
> - a + b, a % b, a & b, a << b, and all other built-in arithmetic expressions;

and:

> rvalue
>
> An rvalue ("right value") expression is an expression that is either a prvalue or an xvalue. [...]
>
> Properties (note: these apply to pre-C++11 rvalues as well):
>
> - An rvalue can't be used as the left-hand operand of the built-in assignment or compound assignment operators.

Perhaps you meant:

`current->data.number += changeValue;`

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thank you!

Comment: Temporary objects are assignable in fact.  Prvalues of built-in type are not assignable (and they are not called temporaries in the C++ standard).

Comment: @M.M I kinda deliberately wrote it. I didn't know how to explain the concept at a beginner-level with out getting into all mess with value types which currently exists but I ended up being incorrect. I've edited the answer. I think it's fine now. Thanks for bringing this up!

Answer (score 0):

In general if you are operating on a linked list you will have something along this form (in pseudocode).

```
currentNode = list.head

while (currentNode isn't null) {
  changeNode(currentNode)
  currentNode = currentNode.next
}
```

Basically you need to iterate though your linked list by preforming your operation on your current node and then moving to the next one.  Of cause the exact way you would implement this psydocode depends on how you have implemented your class.

Comment: Thanks.  My browsers spell checker doesn't know how to spell that word

Comment: @paddy I updated my post so you can see my train of thought.

Comment: @QthePlatypus Thank you. I updated my post so you can seem my train of thought on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is wrong.This line should be more like:

```
 current->data.number  = current->data.number + changeValue
```

Also you should change the data before moving to the next node:

```
void IntegerListClass::AdjustNumbers(int changeValue)
{
nodePtr current;

current = start;

while (current != NULL)
{


    current->data.number  = current->data.number + changeValue
    current = current->link;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this statement:

```
current->data.number + changeValue = current->data.number
```

The compiler is telling you that `current->data.number + changeValue` is not an *lvalue*.  That is, it doesn't refer to a modifiable location in memory.  In fact it's known as an *rvalue*, which is a temporary result.  You are also missing a semi-colon.

To fix this, put the *lvalue* on the left and the *rvalue* on the right:

```
current->data.number = current->data.number + changeValue;
```

A short-hand in C++ is to use the `+=` operator.  Your whole loop should look like this:

```
while (current != NULL)
{
    current->data.number += changeValue;
    current = current->link;
}
```

You could also use a for-loop for a tidier function:

```
void IntegerListClass::AdjustNumbers(int changeValue)
{
    for( nodePtr current = start; current != NULL; current = current->link )
    {
        current->data.number += changeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: @paddy Got it! Thank you. But one more question....how do I output it? since ofstream& fout is not allowed in the parameter list, what should me call be like in the main to output that data? Do I need an return statement?

Comment: Post a separate question, otherwise the comments will be filled up with code and my own questions about you being more specific about what you mean by "output that data".  I'm not going to engage you on that because it's completely unrelated to your original question.  Just post another question.

Comment: @paddy it says I have to wait 45 minutes before posting another question though....